# How/ Is it possible to access Content Ids inside CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, contentplaceholder

How to access ASP:Content IDs or ASP:ContentPlaceHolder IDs inside a CSS without using DIV tags in order to apply styles.
I tried this using normal CSS Syntax but it didn't work. I need to apply styles to content place holder. Thanks

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder"
  runat="server">
     <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="AdminUpdatePanel">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
```

Comment: The very easiest way to get you going would be the following: 1. Run your page and open the developer tools "<asp: tags" get compiled into html at runtime. So have a look what the actual HTML looks like when it runs and apply CSS accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't it work with for example `#Content2 table { .... }` ?

Comment: @LGSon No, Its not working :-(